# Creating a new list for every line in a text file?

Tags: python, list, sorting, text-files

So I'm trying to create a program that will sort the contents of a text file in multiple ways (alphabetical, numerical order etc.). To do this I would need to create a new list for every item in a text file. Say my text file looked like this:

```
Isaac 2 5 3  
Aaron 9 8 10
```

The output for one of the sorting methods (alphabetical, with only the highest score displayed) should look something like this:

```
Aaron 10  
Isaac 5
```

To do this I would need to create a new list for every line in a text file, that way I could sort it multiple ways and I could remove any irrelevant info i.e lower scores. I have tried:

```
mylist = fileName.split("\n")
```

and even:

```
mylist = fileName.readlines()
```

But these just create a big list with a new item for every line, instead of an individual list for every line. Is there any way to do this with either these two methods or another method I haven't heard of?

Comment: Might this be a good application to use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)?

Answer (score 3):

In a first iteration, assuming that `f` is the file object, you could simply do

```
mylist = [line.split() for line in f]
```

This gives you a list of lists like

```
[["Isaac", "2", "5", "3"], ["Aaron", "9", "8", "10"]]
```

However, if you want to sort numbers, you need to convert the strings to integers (or floats?) first, since `"9" > "10"`. How to do this depends on the structure of your data.

Assuming the first element of your line is a name and everything else after that is integers, you can use

```
mylist = []
for line in f:
    items = line.split()
    mylist.append([items[0]] + [int(item) for item in items[1:]])
```

Result:

```
[['Isaac', 2, 5, 3], ['Aaron', 9, 8, 10]]
```

Comment: Using your second method gave me the error:  
  
    'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3,''  
  
I printed the contents of "items" before the error occurred and it looked like:  
  
    '['Isaac', '2', '5', '3,']'  
  
That's all that printed before the error occurred.

Comment: @Airaidios: Well, `"3,"` can't be converted to an integer, the error message made that pretty clear, didn't it? Only strings that contain nothing but ASCII digits (optionally surrounded by whitespace) can be converted like that. My answer works for the example you posted in your question. If that differs from your actual data, there's not much I can do to help unless you specify *exactly* what your data looks like.

Comment: @Airaidios have you changed the input data to separate the numbers by the commas because it looks like thats the problem. Otherwise you can modify @TimPietzcker 's code and change the line `items = line.split()` into this `items = [s.strip() for s in line.split(',')]`. This assumes that your data is like this: `Aaron, 9, 8, 10` instead of `Aaron 9 8 10`

Comment: @dopstar: According to his first comment, the data is not like this - maybe there's a comma at the end of each line - but we have no way to tell if that is always the case...

Answer (score 0):

Using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), here's one way to do it.

N.B.:  I'm a Pandas noob.

Made a data file:

```
$ cat data.txt
Isaac 2 5 3
Aaron 9 8 10
```

and then used pandas with ipython:

```
In [3]: import pandas as pd

In [4]: df = pd.read_table('data.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
       0  1  2   3
0  Isaac  2  5   3
1  Aaron  9  8  10

In [6]: newdf = df.sort(0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x[0],x[1:].max()]),axis=1)

In [7]: newdf
Out[7]: 
       0   1
1  Aaron  10
0  Isaac   5

In [8]: print(newdf.to_string(header=False, index=False))
 Aaron  10
 Isaac   5

In [9]: newdf.values
Out[9]: 
array([['Aaron', 10],
       ['Isaac', 5]], dtype=object)

In [10]: newdf.values.tolist()
Out[10]: [['Aaron', 10], ['Isaac', 5]]
```

Suggestions to simplify this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys so after experimenting with the answers provided I found a stupidly simple way to get what I needed:

```
for line in file.readlines():  
            items = line.split()  
            items = sorted(items, reverse = True)  
            del items[-2:]    
            print(items)
```

Output looks like:

```
['Isaac', '5']  
['Aaron', '9']
```

Comment: Note that the output is not sorted alphabetically.